# Symfony2 Form builder add entity 'Could not load type entity'

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've created a form type in Symfony that extends the Abstract type, and added the fields using the builder, but no matter what I do it won't work!

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('other', 'entity', array(
            'data_class' => 'My\App\DefaultBundle\Entity\Other'
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'runSpeeds' => 'My\App\DefaultBundle\Entity\My',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my';
    }
}
```

> Could not load type "entity" 500 Internal Server Error -
>   InvalidArgumentException

"My" Entity has a column which references the id of "Other" using a foreign key constraint. I want my form to basically have a drop down in the form for "My" that displays all the values from the "name" column in the "Other" entity using the Other.id -> My.other_id as reference.

**Update**

I have an OtherType (Form type) and the following will work:

```
$builder>add('name', new OtherType(), array(
    'data_class' => 'My\App\DefaultBundle\Entity\Other')
)
```

But this displays the entire entity in the form. I only want one field from the Other entity to display, and in a dropdown with the choices

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the required option `class`.

As mentioned in the documentation of [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#class)

**EDIT:**

Moreover you have two syntax issues ("**;**" is missing)

```
$builder->add('name', 'text')
$builder->add('other', 'entity', array(
    'data_class' => 'My\App\DefaultBundle\Entity\Other'
))
```

Comment: No you are providing the option `data_class` not the `class`. Try to replace `data_class` by `class`

Comment: Sorry, was a bit confusing you posting what I initially posted. A corrected version would have been better! Thanks though, but it still errors!

Comment: Thank for your answer. Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640906/how-to-include-in-entity-form-type-some-fields-from-another-entity) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the required `class` attribute, as defined in the basic usage http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage

```
$builder->add('other', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'DefaultBundle:Other'
))
```

If your `Other` class implements a `__toString()` method you can use that to determine the label. You can also use `property` for that:

```
$builder->add('other', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'DefaultBundle:Other',
    'property' => 'name',
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'My\App\DefaultBundle\Entity\My'
    ));
}
```

And change `data_class` to `class` in the following lines:

```
    $builder->add('other', 'entity', array(
        'data_class' => 'My\App\DefaultBundle\Entity\Other'
    ));
```