# Form with field for a object on symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity with normal variables and a variable that is a reference to another object. To build a form in symfony I need to send an object along with the form with the fields I want on the form. How do I do this in this case?

My class with the filed that references another class call site:

```
    private $Site;

    public function getSite()
    {
        return $this->Site;
    }

    public function setSite(Site $Site)
    {
        $this->Site = $Site;
    }
```

My form code:

```
    $builder
        ->add('site')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
        ))
        ->add('termsAccepted', CheckboxType::class, array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => new IsTrue(),
        ))
        ->add('registrar', SubmitType::class)
        ;
```

And haw I create the form:

```
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, $user);
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. So you have an entity - which you gave just a small portion of - and one of the properties is a relation to another table, yes? Would you post the whole entity and tell us which field is related to another entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that form embedding is what you looking for:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html

Similar question here:
[How to include in entity form type some fields from another entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640906/how-to-include-in-entity-form-type-some-fields-from-another-entity)

You have to create another form type (`SiteType`) as representation of fields from the `Site` entity. Than you just add this new field `->add('site', SiteType::class)` to the form builder.